# R5RS scheme code find sum of the even elements in a list(recursive and higher order abstractions)?

Tags: list, recursion, scheme, r5rs

```
(define mylist (list 1 2 3 5 8 9 10))

;;sum of the squares of the even elements of mylist
(define (evens lis)
  (cond (;; Check stop condition 1
         (null? lis)
         '())
        (;; Check stop condition 2: list of length = 1
         (null? (cdr lis))
         '())
        (else
         ;; Check: Building list with second element
         ;; The previous cond clauses have already sorted out
         ;; that lis and (cdr lis) are not null.
         (cons (cadr lis)
               ;; Check: Recurse "the rest of the rest" of lis with cddr
               (evens (cddr lis))))))

(define (sum-even lis)
  (if (null? lis)
  0
  (+ (expt (car lis) 2) (sum-even(cdr lis))))) ;;add all squared even elements

(sum-squared-even (evens mylist))
```

Here is my attempt to find the sum of the squares of the even elements in the list. However, I am really new to r5rs, **is that possible I can write these scheme into only one procedure?** Also, **I was asked to write a second version in terms of map, foldr, and filter**. Hope anyone familiar with r5rs can help me out! Thanks!

Comment: Next time use tag scheme (and/or racket) to have a faster answer, since scheme is much more popular than r5rs.

Comment: Thanks @Renzo for your detailed explanation! It's really help me to understand recursive function. I will get on to look tag scheme now, as I am a true "newbie" to r5rs.

Comment: It's unclear if you're looking for the elements that are even numbers, or the elements that are in an even-numbered position (which is what you've written).

Comment: @Renzo Racket != Scheme. It's like tagging java to get help with a C++ problem. (though PLT makes a very nice implementation of standard schemes in additional to their own non scheme) Tagging version, like r5rs og r6rs, will direct the answers towards a standard.

Comment: BTW. Do you want to sum the element at even positions in the list or  all numbers in the list which are even? Seems both answers assume it's a number property while it seems from the `cadr` that you might be looking for even placed.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your function is wrong since you do not test the numbers of the list for evenness. This should be the correct definition:

```
;;even elements of a list
(define (evens lis)
  (cond (;; Check stop condition
         (null? lis)
         '())
        (;; Check if first element is even,
         ;; return it with the evens of the rest of the list
         (even? (car lis))
         (cons (car lis) (evens (cdr lis))))
        (else
         ;; First element is odd, return only the evens of the rest of the list
         (evens (cdr lis)))))
```

Then, to answer to your first question, this is a solution with a single recursive function:

```
;;sum of the squares of the even elements of a list
(define (sum-square-evens lis)
  (cond ((null? lis)
         0)
        (;; Recurring, first case: the first element is even, so square it
         ;; and add to the result of summing the square of the evens of the rest of the list
         (even? (car lis))
         (+ (expt (car lis) 2)
            (sum-square-evens (cdr lis))))
        (else
         ;; Recurring, when the first element is not even
         ;; the result is obtained by summing the square of the evens of the rest of the list
         (sum-square-evens (cdr lis)))))
```

Finally here is the function written with `foldl-map-filter`:

```
(define (sum-square-evens-2 lis)
  (foldl + 0 (map (lambda(x) (expt x 2)) (filter even? lis))))
```

but note that `foldl` is not a primitive function of R5RS Scheme, so you should run your program with DrRacket with the `#lang racket` specification, or you should define it or load a library in which it is defined.

Here is the meaning of the second function:

1. `filter` applies a predicate to all the elements of a list, a returns a new list containing all the elements that satisfy the predicate. In this case the predicate is `even?`, so the result of `(filter even? lis)` is the list of all the even numbers of `lis`.
2. To this list the `map` high order function is applied, to produce as result the results of the function first argument (in this case a function that squares its argument) applied to its second argument (a list). So the result of `(map ...)` is a new list containing the squares of all the even elements of the original list.
3. Finally, `(foldl + 0 (n1 n2 ...nk))` returns `(...((0 + n1) + n2) + ... + nk)`, since it repeatedly applies the binary function `+` to the elements of the list, using `0` as its first (left) operand. (Note that `foldl` and `foldr` are in this case equivalent, the second one calculating the sum as `(n1 + (n2 + ...(nk + 0)...))`)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it; I'll leave to you the definitions of `sum` and `square`:

```
(sum (map square (filter even? '(1 2 3 5 8 9 10))))
```

It's handy to collect convenience functions like `sum` and `square` in a library that is loaded automatically when you start your Scheme interpreter, so you can write simple expressions like this without delay.

Answer (score 0):

Your `sum_even` has perhaps a wrong name as it will square every element and sum it together, thus `square-sum` is perhaps a better name.

If you wanted the even placed elements to be squared and summed you just use the two procedures you have posted:

```
(define (square-sum-even lst)
  (square-sum (evens lst)))
```